# request.getParameter returns value for only first parameter and null for other url parameters in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, urlencode

I have 3 parameters in my URL. And I have encoded them using 
`URLEncoder.encode(myUrl,"UTF-8")`
My url with encoded parameters looks like this

```
http://localhost/myPage.jsp%3Fparam1%3Daction%26param2%3D3%26param3%3Dhi
```

I specified `pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` in my jsp page and also set `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` before using `request.getParameter("param1")` to get parameter value.

Still I only get the value of first param i.e param1. For other params I get `null`

But if I do double encoding(using `URLEncoder.encode(myEncodedUrl,"UTF-8")`) I can get all three parameters' values. I guess double encoding is not the correct way to do it.

If I replace the `&` with `%2526` instead of `%26`(actual encoded value of `&`) I am getting value of all 3 params. I guess its not correct either.

Please let me know what I am missing in first place.

Comment: I decoded your URL and it looks like this `http://localhost/myPage.jsp?param1=action¶m2=3¶m3=hi`. Can you confirm is that is the characters you intended?

Comment: Yes. I too get that if I decode it. But When I try to use `request.getParameter("param2")`, it gives me `null`.

Comment: 1) Your url encoding is incorrect. `&` needed to separate each parameters. However if your using custom separator then you need to parse the URL yourself. 2) To get the second parameter if `&` used, you just need to do `request.getParameter("m2")`

Comment: I already have `&` to separate params. In my URL, if I replace `&` with `%2526` I get values of all 3 params.

Comment: Jayjay has provided the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're encoding the URL wrong, you shouldn't encode the whole URL:

```
?param1=action&param2=3&param3=hi
```

You should only encode the values of the parameters: 'action', '3'(if it's not an integer) and 'hi'.

Maybe this link will help you.
 [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)